# How to store brackets and numbers separately?

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to decode string into its contents but the programs output is not as intended. 
Output is:

-858993623 444 333

What is -858993623?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

int areaCode;
long phoneNumber1;  
long phoneNumber2;
char bracket1, bracket2, chard;

char tel[]="(555) 444-333";

sscanf(tel, "%c%d%c %ld%c%ld", &bracket1, &bracket2,  &areaCode, &phoneNumber1, &chard, &phoneNumber2 );

printf("%d %ld %ld", areaCode, phoneNumber1, phoneNumber2);

getch();
```

}

Comment: Consider tagging C or C++; you'll get more folk looking at this. I tagged C for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in UB land at the moment: Try `&bracket1, &areaCode, &bracket2`  rather than `&bracket1, &bracket2,  &areaCode`. Everything else looks fine.

Comment: Ahh I feel dumb. Thanks. By the way what is UB?

Comment: Undefined behaviour. Means anything could happen. The output should be regarded as completely spurious.